# Adding a new property to an existing array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik within my React app and have the following initial values, which is just a portion of it:

```
"myInfo": [
            {
                "myId": 0,
                "myName": "Name A",
                "defaultVal": 2
            },
            {
                "myId": 1,
                "myName": "Name B",
                "defaultVal": 4
            }
]
```

What I am attempting to do is to try and add a new property to this array of objects but not having much luck.

My code is as follows:

```
const getAdditionalData = async (id, idx) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/more-data/${id}`);
    const myData = await response.json();

    myInfo[idx].vals = myData;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};        

useEffect(() => {
  myInfo.map((info, index) => {
    getAdditionalData(info.myId, index)
  });
}, []);
```

FYI, the values returned in `myData` is another array of objects that looks like this:

when `myId` = 0 it returns:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'AA'}
 {id: 2, name: 'BB'}]
```

when `myId` = 1 it returns:

```
[{id: 3, name: 'CC'}
 {id: 4, name: 'DD'}
 {id: 5, name: 'EE'}]
```

What I am attempting to do is that while within the array loop, I want to add a new property within `myInfo` array. I tried the following, which didn't work:

`myInfo[idx].vals = myData;`

The end result that I am after is the following:

```
"myInfo": [
            {
                "myId": 0,
                "myName": "Name A",
                "defaultVal": 2,
                "vals": [
                   {id: 1, name: 'AA'},
                   {id: 2, name: 'BB'}
                ]
            },
            {
                "myId": 1,
                "myName": "Name B",
                "defaultVal": 4,
                "vals": [
                   {id: 3, name: 'CC'},
                   {id: 4, name: 'DD'},
                   {id: 5, name: 'EE'}
                ]
            }
]
```

You will see that a new property of `vals` has been added.

Any help would be much appreciated as not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Can you add some expected snippet code?

Comment: what is `values`? is it a react state? if so just mutating won't work, react won't know that it changed

Comment: FYI, I am not receiving any updates and have provided the end result that I am after. I removed the `values` as this is not react state. I am purely trying to add a new property within the `myInfo` array.

Comment: The assignment `myInfo[idx].vals = myData;` should work as expected if both `myInfo` and `myData` are proper JS arrays and objects. I suspect one or both of them are just JSON strings?

Comment: @thabs - unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working as expected and yep, both JSON strings. Not sure what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to use JSON strings like objects. They have to be [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) first.

See the following example.

```
const myInfo = `[
  {
    "myId": 0,
    "myName": "Name A",
    "defaultVal": 2
  },
  {
    "myId": 1,
    "myName": "Name B",
    "defaultVal": 4
  }
]`;

const myData = `[
  {"id": 3, "name": "CC"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "DD"},
  {"id": 5, "name": "EE"}
]`;

const parsedInfo = JSON.parse(myInfo);
const parsedData = JSON.parse(myData);

parsedInfo[0].vals = parsedData;

console.log(parsedInfo[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `myInfo`? A state, class or ref variable? Also take into consideration that `map` returns a brand new array so it doesn't mutate.

You can try this and you should see the updated array in myNewInfo:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const myNewInfo = myInfo.map((info, index) => ({
    ...info,
    vals: getAdditionalData(info.myId, index)
  }));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked from me in native javascript:

```
const getAdditionalData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5500/data.json`);
    const myData = await response.json();
    let newObj = [];
    myData.myInfo.map((data, i) => {
      newObj = [...newObj, { ...data, val: [...valObj[i]] }];
    });
    console.dir(newObj);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};

const valObj = [
  [
    { id: 1, name: "AA" },
    { id: 2, name: "BB" },
  ],
  [
    { id: 3, name: "CC" },
    { id: 4, name: "DD" },
    { id: 5, name: "EE" },
  ],
];

getAdditionalData();


//data.json

{
  "myInfo": [
    {
      "myId": 0,
      "myName": "Name A",
      "defaultVal": 2
    },
    {
      "myId": 1,
      "myName": "Name B",
      "defaultVal": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that you would need to sync the indices of `myInfo` and `valObj`.